# Effect on div sibling

Tags: html, css

I have two siblings div where there are more divs contained inside, like this:

```
<div class="btn_lists">
    <div class="btn green_btn">
        <img src="<?= asset_url() ?>images/escolar_07__1.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-desc-container">
    <div class="btn-desc_1">
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

By default I have btn-desc_1 with display: none;
I want that hovering green_btn applies display: inline-block; on btn-desc_1

How could I do this efficiently?

Comment: what have you tried? if you use latest technology it won't be supported for all browsers, I'm pretty sure that this can be done with html5 and CSS3

Comment: i've tried using adjacent selector like this,
.btn_lists green_btn:hover + .btn-desc-container .btn-desc_1

Comment: Do you mean so that when you hover over .green_btn, it will set display: inline-block; on .btn-desc_1? If so, you may need JavaScript, unless the element are next to each other in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horroristic almost-answer. Probably very unreliable. It is only for demonstration, don't use it. Instead of hovering it works with clicking on the images:

`:checked` is supported only with IE9+: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

Live example, click the kittens: http://jsfiddle.net/bzH7S/2/

```
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="btn" value="1" id="radio1">
    <input type="radio" name="btn" value="2" id="radio2">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="btn_lists">
            <label for="radio1" class="btn btn1"><img src="1"></label>
            <label for="radio2" class="btn btn2"><img src="2"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-desc-container">
            <div class="btn-desc_1"><p>Kitten One</p></div>
            <div class="btn-desc_2"><p>Kitten Second</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body > input {
     display: none;
}

.btn-desc-container > div {
    display: none;
}

#radio1:checked ~ #wrap .btn-desc_1,
#radio2:checked ~ #wrap .btn-desc_2 {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is kind-of cool, I don't think I would use it, but still cool. Probably the best CSS only option though.

Comment: Might want to set visibility to hidden and position to abslute on the inputs to increase the odds of it working across more browsers. This approach will work on most modern browsers, though.

Comment: Updated answer with suggested html structure for production, if you are crazy enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this via CSS. Use jquery piece of code:

```
$('.green_btn').hover(function(){
    $('.btn-desc_1').toggleClass('display-inline');
})
```

like the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nidzix/sWQr9/3/

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this unless `btn_desc1` is a child of `green_btn`, in which this would work:

```
.green_btn:hover > .btn-desc_1
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<div class="btn_lists">
    <div class="btn green_btn">
        <img width='400px' heigh='400px' src="http://www.pieisgood.org/images/slice.jpg" />
        <div class="btn-desc_1">
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

in your CSS.  However, you could use JQuery for this to reach your goal, like **nidzik** says:

```
$('.green_btn').hover(function(){
    $('.btn-desc_1').toggleClass('display-inline');
})
```

**[Here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Lat/)**

Comment: This won't work because .btn-desc_1 is not a child of .green_btn.

Comment: Still won't work. `btn-desc_1` isn't a sibling of `green_btn`.

Comment: is it possible to say something like 
.btn_lists .green_btn:hover ~ .btn-desc_container .btn-desc_1 
??

Comment: `.btn-desc_container` isn't a general sibling of `.green_btn`. You can stop trying different combos now, it's not possible without JavaScript.

Comment: @j08691 I realize.  I'm glad to report my answer now makes sense.